# calculate date of next monday to a given date

Tags: perl, datetime

I am looking to return the date of the next monday of a given date. In case the given date is already a monday the date should remain the same.

From another post I found a script to calculate the previous monday of a given date using DateTime.

```
use DateTime;

my $date = DateTime->new(year => 2011, month => 6, day => 11); 
my $desired_dow = 1;            # Monday 
$date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7); 
print "$date\n";
```

(credit to cjm)

I simply cannot find out how to modifiy this in order to calculate the next monday (and not the previous one).
Can someone help?

Comment: It would be nice if you read the documentation of [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.74/lib/DateTime.pm)

Comment: @Nikhil actually I did.. and could not find the mechanism used above (e.g. the % 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7);
```

to

```
$date->add(days => ($desired_dow - $date->day_of_week) % 7);
```

or you could have optionally just added a week to your "old" Monday:

```
$date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7); 
$date->add(days => 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the accepted answer (the `add` part) is incorrect.

This is what I use:

```
my $date = DateTime->now;
my $current_dow = $date->day_of_week;
my $desired_dow = 1; # Monday
$date->add( days => 7 - $current_dow + $desired_dow );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $date = shift || die "No date given\n\n\tUsage: ./test.pl 2017-07-17, please note the format, CCYY-MM-DD\n\n";

my @date = split /-/, $date;
$date[0] -= 1900;
$date[1]--;

die "Invalid date: $date\n" unless @date == 3;

my $now = &timelocal(0, 0, 12, reverse @date);

do{
    $now += 24 * 60 * 60;
#}while ((strftime('%u', localtime $now) != 1) && (strftime('%u', localtime $now) != 5) && (strftime('%u', localtime $now) != 3));  ## For Multiple days, in case you want to find either, next monday, friday or wednesday
}while (&strftime('%u', localtime $now) != 1);      #Values should be from 1 to 7, including...

my @array_of_time     = localtime($now);
my $formatted_time     = &strftime( "%Y%m%d", @array_of_time );
print ("Next Monday-[$formatted_time]\n");
```