# Find the first instance of weekday in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am trying to find the first instance of a specific weekday in a month, for example the first Monday of a specific month/year that I give it.

Messing around with `DateTime` I know I can create my date object with

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year     => $year,
    month    => $month
);
```

and then I can even use `$dt->day_of_week` to get a 1-7 back to know what day of the week it is. My original plan was to do this and simply loop through one week and increase the day by one each time,  the problem is that it seems like once I create a `DateTime` object, it becomes immutable, and so I can't update the day.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, if you know the weekday of the first day of the month, then you don't need to loop to find the next Monday (or whatever day), it's just simple arithmetics. Also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394466/calculate-date-of-next-monday-to-a-given-date

Comment: That is definitely an option, but I feel like from an efficiency standpoint it's relatively ineffective, I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it, maybe using something other than `DateTime`.

Comment: The simple arithmetics is definitely more efficient than looping over weekdays.

Comment: Every time you create a new object that has a huge overhead, compared to what simple arithmetic costs. This is a good example for trying out a Benchmark, to see how much slower this would be. In reality, if you don't do it for millions of data sets, it' doesn't matter. But it will be several orders of magnitude of difference in run time.

Comment: Re "*once I create a DateTime object, it becomes immutable*", Not so. DateTime objects are mutable, as you can see in my answer. I have no idea why you bring it up, though. If the object immutable, you'd simply use `$dt = $dt->add(...);` instead of `$dt->add(...);`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) which is a core library <del>(and its objects are mutable)</del>. Also, you don't need to loop over the days, just use math to find the number of days to add.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Time::Piece;

for my $year (2000 .. 2020) {
    for my $month (1 .. 12) {
        my $tp = 'Time::Piece'->strptime("$year$month", '%Y%m');
        $tp += Time::Seconds::ONE_DAY * ((8 - $tp->day_of_week) % 7);
        say join "\t", $tp->mday, $tp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re "*its objects are mutable*", [No, they're not](https://pastebin.com/7xfWwvTS). Time::Piece makes it a point of making it look like you do one thing when you're really doing another. All this magic is part of the reason why Time::Piece is so incredibly complicated and best to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about DateTime objects, the very same approach choroba took for Time::Piece objects can be used for DateTime objects.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use DateTime;

for my $year (2000 .. 2020) {
    for my $month (1 .. 12) {
        my $dt = DateTime->new( year => $year, month => $month );
        $dt->add( days => ((8 - $dt->day_of_week) % 7) );
        say join "\t", $dt->day, $dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like code below should do it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;

my $year  = 2056;
my $month = 11;
my $find  = 'monday';

                                    #  ucfirst lc - for consistency
say findDayOfWeek($year,$month,$find) . " is " . ucfirst lc $find;

sub findDayOfWeek {             # find first occurrence day of week 
    my $year  = shift;
    my $month = shift;
    my $dow   = shift;          # day of week

    $dow = ucfirst lc $dow;     # ucfirst lc - for consistency

    my %dayOfWeek = ( 
                        Monday => 1, Tuesday => 2, Wednesday => 3, 
                        Thursday => 4, Friday => 5, Saturday => 6,
                        Sunday => 7
                    );
    my $date;
    my $day = 1;

    my $dt = DateTime->new(
                year    => $year,
                month   => $month,
                day     => $day
            );

    my $dayOfWeek = $dt->day_of_week;

    if( $dayOfWeek != $dayOfWeek{$dow} ) {      # we are missed the target
        $day += $dayOfWeek{$dow}>$dayOfWeek     # correct it
                ? $dayOfWeek{$dow}-$dayOfWeek
                : 7+$dayOfWeek{$dow}-$dayOfWeek;
    }

    $date = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day;

    return $date;
}
```

Output

```
2056-11-06 is Monday
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) (which is by design immutable):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Moment;
for my $year (2000 .. 2020) {
    for my $month (1 .. 12) {
        my $monday = Time::Moment->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 1)
            ->with_day_of_week(1); # 1 == Monday
        # correct the week if that day was in the previous month
        $monday = $monday->plus_weeks(1) if $monday->month != $month;
        say join "\t", $monday->day_of_month, $monday;
    }
}
```